# populate UITableView on click

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I have a UITableView that parses xml data from a webserver.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 

// parse data from xml

}
```

when the view loads, it automatically populates the tablecell, but i dont want it to be like that. I want to populate the table cells only when the user taps a button.

I did something like, hide the table view then show it when the user taps, but i also dont want it to be like that, i want it to only parse and populate the cells when the user taps the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not set tableView Delegate methods in .xib file. just set them in your view Controller. Then when button is tapped just use reloadData method of tableView.
 Hope this will help.

Comment: wow thanks! i added my tableview.delegate = self; and tableview.datasource = self; when the user taps the button.